# How I can find out IPs of slave nodes where currently map reduce task is running or about to run for a given Job?

Tags: hadoop

I want to find out IPs of slave nodes where currently map reduce job is running or about to run for a given Job.
Is there any method to do this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any job, you can view the list of running tasks through the Job Scheduler Web UI - this will detail the nodes on which the task is running.

As for where tasks are about to run - this is not neccessarily decided in advance. As slots become available on a node, the Job Scheduler (there are a number which behave differently depending on your needs) identifies a job task which will run on that node (based upon a number of criteria, hopefully honoring data locality where it can) and instructs the task tracker on that node to run the specific task.

Programatically, look at the javadocs for the JobClient class, it should be able to acquire information about the running tasks, and their node names (you'll probably need to do a DNS lookup to get the actual IPs i imagine)

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop comes with several web interfaces which are by default (see conf/hadoop-default.xml) available at these locations:
`http://localhost:50030/ – web UI for MapReduce job tracker(s`)
 `http://localhost:50060/ – web UI for task tracker(s)`
 `http://localhost:50070/ – web UI for HDFS name node(s)`

Thanks to @Chris..
Programatically, look at the javadocs for the JobClient class, it should be able to acquire information about the running tasks, and their node names.